# Spring Boot Rest API validation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have the following dependency in the pom.xml for spring boot validation and controller method argument updated with @Valid annotation but still no validation errors when I submit a request with null or not empty values. Any Idea like why validation not getting trigged even though hibernate validation library on the classpath.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  @RequestMapping("hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> message(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request)
    {





 public class MyRequest {
    @NotNull(message = "Client ID is mandatory")
    @NotEmpty
    private String clientId;

    @NotEmpty private String employId;
```

Comment: What happens when you submit a request with data not following the validation rules? Do you at least see a 404 BAD request status?

Answer (score 1):

anotations **@NotEmpty** and **@NotNull** and **@Valid** must be imported from **javax.validation**  .... They are all in the **jakarta.Validation api specifications** otherwise it won't work

Comment: I am doing the imports from  javax.validation.constraints.* package  but still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine just add **@Validated** annotation at Controller class level. I hope this works.